# Legend for custom function in R

Tags: r

I have a custom function that runs a `ttest` and graphs the `t-distribution`. I want my legend to say

```
"P-value = x"
```

where `X` is the `P-value` from the test. `X` should be dynamic and

```
"p-value = X"
```

should be the only thing in the legend. How do I create this in `base R`? I generated the distribution with `base R` so I would prefer not to use `ggplot2` because I would need to recode everything.

Comment: You need to show some code. To add a legend to plot you can use the `legend` function.

Comment: Hi Nikolas! Does the answer below solve your issue? If so, please feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the v sign next to the start of the answer. This way, others can see that the issue has been resolved. Otherwise, please feel free to point out in which ways the answer fails to address your problem, and maybe we can improve upon it.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is an object that holds the p-value, you can use `paste0("p-value = ", x)` to create a simple character containing your text and the p-value. Then the issue is just about printing this text to your graph. There are many ways, for instance,

```
pval <- 0.05
pstr <-paste0("My p-value is ", pval)

plot(x=1:5, y=1:5)
text(x=3, y=1, label = pstr) # creates text at the bottom
legend(x="top", legend = pstr) # creates legend at the top
```

Here, you can see the usage and how it looks depending on whether or not you print it with `text` or `legend`.

[image]